# Where to place the Asynctask in the Application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wonder where to place the AsyncTask in the Application? Can I place it in onCreate Method of my Main Activity?

Can anybody please tell me where I can place the Asynctask method in the Application?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here for a good explanation of how to use `AsyncTask`: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

It is most convenient to place the `AsyncTask` as a `private class` (i.e. an inner class) inside the `Activity` where you need to use it.