# Where's the elegant place to put Endpoint Builder and AsyncTask methods for the generated Endpoint methods

Tags: java, google-app-engine

read [Where to place the Asynctask in the Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932075/where-to-place-the-asynctask-in-the-application)
and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Android Studio will generate Endpoint class and Client Libraries for a POJO class with 5 useful methods (get, insert, list, remove, and update).

Attempting these methods on the UI thread is disallowed to protect latency, so calling these methods has to happen on another thread.  Many examples show extending AsyncTask as a solution.

For example, I generate endpoints etc for a class called Doctor, and add this private class inside MainActivity in order to add a new Doctor to the database:

```
private class insertDoctorTask extends AsyncTask<Doctor, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(Doctor... ds) {
            long res = 1;
            try {
                Doctor result = endpoint.insertDoctor(ds[0]).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                res = 0;
                }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

I will need the same code in other Activities and I'm reluctant to copy and paste it all over the place.  What's an elegant way to make this and its companion Tasks (getDoctorTask, listDoctorTask, removeDoctorTask, updateDoctorTask) available to the Activities so that the code is only in one place?  And where's the proper place to initialize the endpoint?

Comment: I created a package called Tasks with a public class called insertDoctorTask2 the same as above.  Since "endpoint" is a static property of MainActivity (?) i had to add Doctorendpoint myendpoint; to Doctor to carry endpoint over to the method.  It seems incorrect to build the endpoint in MainActivity if I'm going to need it for other activities.  I think I need to have a thread hanging around that builds endpoint so I can use it regardless of activity...

Comment: `Doctorendpoint.Builder builder  = new Doctorendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),null);
        builder.setApplicationName("M25");
        builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
        endpoint = builder.build();` is what I mean when I refer to 'build the endpoint'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of points:

- I would tend to keep `AsyncTask` as private withing the specific Activity, since it is better to link it to the lifecycle of the Activity.
- If you are trying to reuse the code in general from different parts (activities) in your Android application, I believe you should look at writing a `Service`